# How do I start a User Prompt in SAS EG Code

Tags: sas, prompt

Is it possible to define and start a user prompt by starting a SAS EG program, a code? and if yes what's the syntax?

Comment: Try `%window` and `%display` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you refer to prompting for input from a data step or from macro code. That does not work in Enterprice Guide (EG), but there is another sollution.

Each EG project has a set of user defined prompts, which are actually just a global macro variable with specifications on the type of data it can contain, a default value etc.

Each step (program, transformation) can have prompts from the project associated to it. When you start that step, you will be prompted for values. In your code, you can then use these macro variables.

To start working with it: right click a step to which you want to associate a prompt and select properties. Activate the prompt tab and click the [Prompt Manager] button. (There is another way to open the prompt manager, but no-one ever uses it.)

In the prompt manager, you can define the prompts. Bear in mind they will be shared among the steps to which you associate them, so chose macro variable names and wordings that make sense throughout your project.

Once the prompts are defined, you can associate them with your step and use the macro variables where you need them.

Success

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll try and give you feedback